# Solving $y'+cy=be^{ax}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am quite confused to solve this ODE
$$y'+c y=b e^{ax}$$
I am doing as follows

$$LHS=0\quad  y (x)= ke^{-cx}$$
$$RHS\quad  \frac{b}{a}e^{ax}$$
Add them up
$$y (x)=ke^{-cx}+\frac{b}{a}e^{ax}$$
But wrong! 
Where is my problem?

Comment: RHS is only a solution of $c=0$

Comment: So what should l do?

Comment: Use method of integrating factor.

Comment: sub in $y(x)=d e^{ax}$ and carefully solve for $d$

Comment: Thanks. This will give as $$d=b/(a+b)$$ which leads me to solution for RHS.

Comment: you should get $d(a+c)=b$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using method of integrating factor:

$$\frac{dy}{dx} + cy = be^{ax} $$

Using integrating factor $e^{cx}$

$$ \frac{d}{dx}(ye^{cx}) = be^{x(a+c)}$$

$$ ye^{cx} = \int be^{x(a+c)} \ dx$$

$$  ye^{cx} = \frac{b(e^{x(a+c)})}{(a+c)} + D $$

where $D$ is a constant of integration

$$ y = \frac{be^{ax}}{a+c} + De^{-cx}$$

You can go through the following [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrating_factor) to learn more about the method of integrating factors in case you're not familiar with it.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

We can find an integrant factor, i. e. a function $\mu$ such that $$\mu(x)\dfrac{dy}{dx}+c\mu(x)y$$
be an exact diferential (derivative).

A function as $\mu(x)=\exp\left[\int c\,dx\right]=e^{cx}$ works well:
\begin{align}
e^{cx}\frac{dy}{dx}+ce^{cx}y&=e^{cx}be^{ax}\\
\frac{d}{dx}\left(e^{cx}y\right)&=be^{(a+c)x}\\
\end{align}

Then, by integrating both sides we can find a solution.